# Locate "file upload" button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the button shown below (image and HTML) and am trying to click it.

Selenium is unable to locate it - I have tried locating by both xpath and by ID.

[image]

```
<input id="wsUpload1" type="file" name="file">
```

XPATH:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="wsUpload1"]')
element.click()
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Here is the exception thrown by Selenium:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id="wsUpload1"]"}

Comment: Post the url or find yourself if the element is inside a frame. You will have to do browser.switch_to.frame("FrameName")

Comment: Is the button inside `<iframe>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities

1. Duplicate web element with same id in the page.
2. Element may be in frame. You need to switch to frame
3. Trying to access the web element before page is loading.Give some wait time.

Comment: I have solved it - the driver opens a tab on a side panel and the button is in the tab. There seems to be a few ms delay between clicking the tab and the button appearing so I added a wait until element is clickable and that seems to work.

Comment: @Lucky I have same problem but these three possibilities is not applicable to me. Please help if any

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your button wasn't found, maybe it's because of quotes (although it should show you error in that case), try with `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='wsUpload1']")` and see if it works. I'm not sure is your button already rendered on the page or you trigger it somehow so it's not there yet?
`NoSuchElementException` is thrown because your targeted element couldn't be found on that page, it could be that you are on the wrong page, element is not rendered yet so you should wait for it to appear, element could be in some iframe etc etc, it's hard to say when I don't know how your page works.

But if you are trying to upload something you should perform `sendKeys()` on that button (with path of file which are you trying to upload), not `click()` on it. This is how selenium upload works.

Comment: Still not locating the button.

Comment: @acikojevic, using `send_keys()` is a good point, however, it won't solve current issue. Try to provide with some possible options of how to avoid `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: "I'm not sure is your button already rendered on the page or you trigger it somehow so it's not there yet."?

Comment: @acikojevic I have solved it - the driver opens a tab on a side panel and the button is in the tab. There seems to be a few ms delay between clicking the tab and the button appearing so I added a wait until element is clickable and that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it - the driver opens a tab on a side panel and the button is in the tab. There seems to be a few ms delay between clicking the tab and the button appearing so I added a wait until element is clickable and that seems to work.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='wsUpload1']"))).click()
```